# Discrete lattice polymer simulations

Tags: software, software-recommendations, monte-carlo, polymers

I am trying to develop phase coexistence curves for generic polymers. Of course, I can use standard Flory theory free energy functionals to do this, but I want to define my nearest neighbor polymer-polymer and polymer-solvent interaction energies explicitly, and run numerical experiments.

I am thinking about running Monte Carlo simulations of polymers on a discrete lattice. My question is, does such software exist? I want to plant a polymer on a lattice along with solvent molecules and examine the behavior of the system after $N$ moves.

Comment: I gave +1 long ago, but how is this going so far? Have you learned anything about the question since asking it, that you might be able to share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ironically, there exist no on-lattice software for such a Flory-Huggins software. This is primarily because there are no set standards for running such simulations!

Most people run their own DIY code to do this stuff.